# mapping j function (used defined) over a list

Tags: function, j

I've written my own version of the exponential (^) function which works fine for simple scalars :

3 : '+/ (y&^%!) i.50'

It doesn't work over a list, so I thought of modifying it with "0

3 : '+/ (y"0&^%!) i.50'

This works over a list but gives the wrong answers.

Two questions arise:

1) Given my usage of "0 doesn't work, is there one that does ?

2) If I don't have access to a functional definition like this, what is the best way to apply it to the individual elements of an array ?

Comment: What results are you expecting? `^10` gives `22026.5` whereas `3 : '+/ (y&^%!) i.50' 10` gives `27.1828`.

Comment: 3 : '+/ (y&^%!) i.50' 10 gives 22026.5 which unless my eyes are going funny is the same copy as yours ?

Comment: Oops, you're right. The version with `"0` gives `27.1828`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the rank conjunction `"0` over the function you want to map `(y&^%!)`, instead of its argument `y`:

```
 3 : '+/(y&^%!)"0 i.50'
```

However, the precision isn't as good as the native `^`:

```
   a =: 3 : '+/(y&^%!)"0 i.50' 4 4 $ 10+i.20
   b =: ^ 4 4 $ 10+i.20
   a = b
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```